# git rebase -i master doesn't allow to edit first branch commit

Tags: git, rebase

Consider the following scenario:

```
master -> (more commits) -> a commit
                                \ 
    my_branch                      commit 1 -> commit 2 -> commit 3
```

I want to go back to `my_branch@commit 1` and edit some files, so assuming `my_branch` is on `commit 3` I simply do `git rebase -i master` and mark `edit` commit 1. However, when git stops on that commit, it doesn't show any changes ie: git status simply returns empty none of the files that were changed/delete/modified in that commit. I suspect it has something to do with `commit 1` being the first commit of the branch but I can't find an easy solution to this.

Thanks and feel free to point me to previous answers but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit will stop *after* the commit is applied.... so if you run `git status`, it will tell you that there's nothing to do... but if you check the log, you will see that the commit is already in history (actually, it's `HEAD`).... so, now edit the files that you need, add that and run `git commit --amend`.... then `git rebase --continue`

Comment: Thanks, seems I can achieve what I want by simply doing `git reset HEAD^` once I am editing the commit.

Comment: I might be wrong but by doing that you are moving the branch pointer to the _previous_ commit. Check with git log. If you meant to _edit_, then you are getting out of the _normal_ flow.... it's ok **if you really know what you are getting into**.

Comment: `git reset HEAD^` isn't necessary in this case. This is useful when you want to split an old commit into multiple. As @eftshift0 mentioned, you should just `git commit --amend` new changes. With optional `--no-edit` if you don't want to change the commit message